# Executing .m file with Octave GUI command window leads to error: no such file

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I'm pretty new to working with Octave (v 6.1.0) and could not figure out what's the problem with executing a .m-file via command window yet.

Octave is installed locally on my computer.

My working directory is in subdirectory on a server. The hierarchy of that server is like:

*Server:/access/access/no_access/no_access/access/my_working_directory*

With octave I can open and edit the scripts in *my_working_directory*.

Using the **pwd** command in the octave command window also returns: *Server:/access/access/no_access/no_access/access/my_working_directory*

When i want to execute the .m script I receive an error like:
**error: no such file 'server:\access\access\file2execute.m**

It seems like a path for the ocatve command tool is not set correctly, therefore it's searching in the wrong folder for the script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Octave has problems with a path including spaces like:

*Server:/access/access/no_access/no access folder/access/my_working_directory*

If it's not possible to change the folder's name, you can mount the "my_working_directory" folder as a new drive of your computer (win explorer > computer > map network drive).

After that, open Octave again and change the working directory using the new path with the mounted folder. This worked for me.